# Отключить работу событий у элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Есть такая проблема. У меня есть WPF приложение-клиент для работы с VNC. Я использую WinForms элемент из VncSharp для вывода потока. У этого элемента есть события, прописанные в dll-файле.
Когда нажимаешь мышкой на этот элемент, вываливается System.Exception, потому что он не может обработать код, изначально прописанный в событии этого элемента. Обработчик я не добавлял, я так понимаю он изначально там есть.

Срабатывает вот этот метод из элемента:

```
        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
        {
            UpdateRemotePointer();
            base.OnMouseUp(mea);
        }
```

Элемент я добавляю через WindowsFormsHost из System.Windows.Forms.Intregration, возможно он добавляет обработчики.
Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?
И можно как-то выключить обработку этого события у элемента, или у WindowsFormsHost'а, если проблема в нем.

Comment: А альтернативу найти, не? Ведь явно костыль делаете, причем очень жирный. К примеру, первый попавшийся [VncDotnet.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VncDotnet.WPF/), уверен, есть другие решения.

Comment: Пробовал этот пакет. Заказчику нужно подключаться к конкретному VNC-серверу. Решение, которое вы скинули не коннектится к нему, к сожалению. Нужно что-то изобретать с этим.

Comment: А если не вызывать `base.OnMouseUp(mea);`?

Comment: Этот метод - не мой код, а код из dll-файла, который вызывает ошибку, потому что вызывается этот метод. При том что я не добавлял обработчик MouseUp, но он все же вызывается

Comment: Я вам дал лишь жирный намек на то, что ваше решение очень странное и стоит найти альтернативу. Ссылку я привел как показатель того, что альтернатива для WPF есть. `не коннектится к нему, к сожалению` - наверно стоит разобраться почему? Поймите, вы сейчас скажем так, берете дорогой спорткар и засовываете в него движок от запорожца, вы уверены, что это вам надо? Уверены, что это единственный вариант? Я вот нет...

Comment: Отнаследоваться и переопределить реализацию этого метода никак?

Comment: `Этот метод - не мой код` это коммерческая разработка или открытый код? Если второе, то склонируйте себе репозиторий, внесите изменения в код и пересоберите библиотеку.